# php preg_match a date format "yyyy-MM"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to use a modified preg format from [preg_match: check birthday format (dd/mm/yyyy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720977/preg-match-check-birthday-format-dd-mm-yyyy) to match credit card expiration dates (yyyy-MM formats)

```
    if (!preg_match('/([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})/', $expirationDate, $matches)) {
        throw new Services_Payment_Exception('Card expiration date is invalid');
    }
```

For some reason, it also validate invalid values such as 20111-02 (invalid year). 
What am I doing wrong here? I want to confirm the year is 4 digits and the month is 2 digits (01, 02.. 12)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anchor your regexp:

```
preg_match('/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})$/', $expirationDate, $matches)
```

Your regexp didn't do what you expected because it matches "0111-02" substring of "20111-02".

[Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` and `$` match particular positions within the input string: `^` matches the beginning of the string and `$` matches the end.

Note also that there is no need to escape the hyphen since it only has a special function in `[]`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `^` and `$` anchors:

```
if (!preg_match('/^([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})$/', $expirationDate, $matches)) {
    throw new Services_Payment_Exception('Card expiration date is invalid');
}
```

to ensure the whole string matches the pattern.

In your example 20111-02 matches because it matches the `0111-02` part of `20111-02`.

Answer (score 2):

It's matching `0111-02`, which fits your requirements.

Change:

```
'/([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})/'
```

to:

```
'/^([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})$/'
```

so it only checks against the entirety of the string.

Answer (score 2):

try this: 
     `if (!preg_match('/^([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})/', $expirationDate, $matches)) {`

Answer (score 2):

Try this it will help check both date format and check if the date if valid or not:

```
if (!preg_match('/^([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})$/', $expirationDate, $matches)) {
    throw new Services_Payment_Exception('Card expiration date is wrong format');

}else if ( !strtotime($expirationDate) ){
    throw new Services_Payment_Exception('Card expiration date is invalid');
}
```