# How to validate date and time in same variable using Codeigniter

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Users are able to choose a date and time in a custom pop-up box.

It currently looks like this when users input the time and date:

```
DD.MM.YYY HH.MM
```

How can I validate this format in Codeigniter upon submitting, using the form validation library?

Comment: You just want a regex to match this?  a regex to match your given pattern is this: `[0-3][0-9].[0-1][0-9].\d{4}\s[0-1][0-9].[0-6][0-9]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter - Date format - Form Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359158/codeigniter-date-format-form-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Use this `regex`

```
(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).(0[1-9]|1[1-2]).\d{4}\s([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]).[0-5][0-9]
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/ahfiuh/5) is the working example of it