# Quickest way to catch an invalid input in php

Tags: php, error-handling

From an HTML document, I am getting two value

```
$dateStart = $_GET['date_1']; //date starting search
$dateEnd = $_GET['date_2']; //date starting search
```

Does PHP offer a feature that allows me to check if the input don't match the format `dd/mm/yy` or must I nest conditions?

Comment: You can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for it.

Comment: you can use date("d/m/Y", strtotime($str)); and check using if conditions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720977/preg-match-check-birthday-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preg\_match: check birthday format (dd/mm/yyyy)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720977/preg-match-check-birthday-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Validate your date

```
if (DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $date)) {
    echo "Date is valid";
} else {
    echo "Date is not valid";
}
```

### More generally, if you want to validate "stuff"

Use PHP "embedded filters" with `filter_var()`. [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). You can use it for a lot of "standard" filters or with your regex. In the case of `dd/mm/yy` dates you can use a custom regex:

```
$regex = '~^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}$~';
print filter_var("01/01/2017",FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,["options" => ["regexp"=> $regex]]);
```

Beware, this will validate also `22/22/22` which is not correct, so use the first proposed date validation, I used it only as example ;)

Comment: Does this need any external librairies? Can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Nevermind. The issue was i wasn't using capital 'y'. Lower case y only takes 2 digits for the year. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: It doesn't seem to catch everything though.  `$dateStart = $_GET['date_1']; if (DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateStart )){ ` doesn't catch 48/12/1975.

Comment: That's because is not a valid date. Use regex instead